# lodash using groupBy on Object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use the groupBy from lodash and I want to achieve something like below.
I have this code and I want to convert it from this

```
 [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'campaign_application_view',
    description: 'Campaign Apply - View',
    category: 'Campaign'
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'pixel_application_view',
    description: 'Pixel Apply - View',
    category: 'Pixels'
  }
 ];
```

To this

```
{
  Campaign: {
    selected: [],
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'campaign_application_view',
        description: 'Campaign Apply - View',
        category: 'Campaign'
      }
    ]
  },
  Pixels: {
    selected: [],
    items: [{
        id: 2,
        name: 'pixel_application_view',
        description: 'Pixel Apply - View',
        category: 'Pixels'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

1. add keys to the items.
2. add another key

lodash `_groupBy` just lets me group it like `{Campaign: [], Pixels: []}`

Comment: Once you have it in the above shape it's not hard to return the shape you want:
`{ Campaign: { selected: [], items: grouped.Campaign }, Pixels: { ... } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping use `_.mapValues()` to convert to the required form:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"campaign_application_view","description":"Campaign Apply - View","category":"Campaign"},{"id":2,"name":"pixel_application_view","description":"Pixel Apply - View","category":"Pixels"}];

const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(arr, 'category'),
  items => ({
    selected: [],
    items
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```